# Using PHP win32_query_service_status() function on 64-bit Windows

Tags: php, windows, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

```
PHP version: 5.3.5 
Apache version 2 
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
```

I am trying to monitor and restart Windows services from a PHP script. When I use this function:

> win32_query_service_status()

I get error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function win32_query_service_status()

This works on a 32-bit Windows server that has PHP v5.2.6
From this other server, I copied the php_win32service.dll to extensions folder and enabled it in my PHP.ini file. Still does not work.
Is there any alternative for 64-bit computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following URL, which provides a link to the [PEAR extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/win32service.installation.php) for use with PHP 5.3.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the php_win32service-svn-20091011-5.3-vc6-x86.zip from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ and used the php_win32service.dll from there. It works now!!!